# How to extract the first column in a file with multi-character delimeter?

Tags: sed, files, string, search

I have a file in which I use a string like `<xxxxx>` to separate the fields. This was a choice to avoid problems with the comma separated fields and other types of single characters due to the nature of strings in the columns which may contain some of these special characters.

I want to extract the first column. I used:

```
cat myfile.txt | cut -d '<xxxxx>' -f1 > out.txt
```

But I got error saying that the delimeter must be a single character. 
Q: How can I extract the first columns (which is before the first occurrence of `<xxxxx>`?

Comment: CSV has rules for how to deal with fields containing commas and newlines etc. (quote fields, double up internal double quotes). Libraries for working with CSV data are readily available for most languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
echo "This is it"|awk -F '<xxxxx>' '{print $1}'
```

Note that the field separator (argument to `-F`) is a regular expression, so if any characters in the separator are special in regexes, you'll need to escape them.